# paintEvent is not getting called in a custom button derived from QAbstractButton

Tags: qt, qt4, paintevent, qabstractbutton

I'm trying to create a custom button, derived from `QAbstractbutton`.

I have overridden the `paintEvent`. However, my button is not visible in my widget.

What I see is that the `paintEvent` is not getting called even after calling `update`/`repaint`/`show` on my button.

What could be the missing link here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paintEvent` on an object won't be called unless the object has a non-zero width and height.  My guess (and absent any example code, it is a pure guess) is that you've just created one with a 0 width or height, and are expecting it to draw.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!I did not know qt optimises on paintEvent() in this case. When my class was derived from QWidget, paintEvent() would work properly(even with not size set initially). For this case(QAbstractbutton derived), I had to set some width and height in the constructor to get it working!

Comment: Just simply reimplement sizeHint in your custom button and calculate proper size for data contained in button